# Change data value with reactivity in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to reduce the value of a data property in every 1 second as follows:

```
  data() {
    return {
      timer: null
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.timer = 50;
    window.setInterval(() => {
      this.$set(this, 'timer', this.timer - 1)
    }, 1000);
  },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/8179/

In the Vue devTool, the `timer` is not automatically updated. However, in the jsfiddle, the output is getting updated. Is this reactive? If not, how can I make it reactive?

Comment: It's working as expected, what's the problem?

Comment: When I open up the vue devtool, the `timer` value is not updating. I'm wondering if it's usual or the reactivity is lost.

Comment: If the reactivity was lost, who would be updating the DOM do you think?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the data get updated in Vue Dev Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838363/why-doesnt-the-data-get-updated-in-vue-dev-tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @connexo already mentioned in the comment section `timer` is indeed reactive. This is why it changes its value in the template.

The only reason for this I could think of is that you don't include `timer` in the component template in your environment. There's a related [Github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/393) describing that so far if there's no DOM elements affected by data, vue-devtools won't be updated either.